# WordPress plugin create trigger not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, database-trigger

So I have a create trigger script which works absolutely great in PHP MyAdmin in MySQL.

But when i try to fire the exact same trigger SQL script within my plugin. It fails to be created in MySQL and the most annoying part is that WordPress doesn't give me any errors at all.

I'm trying to create my trigger through a WordPress activate function in PHP within my plugin.

All my other SQL scripts works in this activate function. It's just the trigger which isn't working.

I'm quite sure the problem lies within how i fire the script in the end

**Example:**

```
        global $wpdb;
        $comments = $wpdb->prefix . "comments";

        $createTrigger = 
                        "
                        DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS upd_trigger;
                        DELIMITER //
                        CREATE TRIGGER upd_trigger
                        AFTER INSERT 
                            ON  $comments 
                            FOR EACH ROW 

                        BEGIN

                        //some code

                        END //
                        DELIMITER ;"; 

        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        $wpdb->query( $createTrigger );
```

**I have also tried the following functions:**

dbDelta( $createTrigger );

mysqli_multi_query( $wpdb->dbh, $createTrigger );

So i'm kind of lost on why this isn't working.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the actual database schema to see if it went through? There are two considerations here. First, `dbdelta` is garbage and strips out a loooooooooooooooooooooooot of perfectly valid sql. Second, your db user may not actually have the correct access rights to create triggers (often they don't for security reasons, because applications should generally not be able to create executable logic in most situations to prevent leaving hacking vulnerabilities).

Comment: If your db user has access rights, you will need to use `mysqli` or `pdo` to circumvent the overly opinionated (and pretty terrible) database layer provided with WordPress. Otherwise, you will need to loosen the permissions for the database user (and may also need to do the prior also).

Comment: Thank for your answer. Yes it does not get created. I can't find it within the triggers in MySQL. Is there a way I can give the admins of the website who activate the plugin the right to execute the trigger script? Can I include the rights in my current script? That would be great. Do you know how to check if the user have access right?

Comment: AFAIK providing DB users any permissions is something only DB / server admins can do. I don't think it's possible to manage that from a plugin (it would be a big security hole, as mopsyd pointed out). If you plan to distribute your plugin, you either warn users that it requires the ability to create triggers or you find a different, non trigger based way to achieve what you're after.

Comment: I would consider not pushing logic into the data layer at all if possible, and using a php based solution in place of that to perform the subsequent inserts. When you work within the bounds of an existing opinionated system, application, or framework, you have to model your logic to conform to the existing opinion of the original developers to avoid introducing bugs.

Comment: From the looks of your code, this is intended to be an upgrade script, which is not particularly terrible to have a little extra overhead running with extra queries, as it will typically be running infrequently and not at all for public end users. When your logic will be hit by everyone (or at significant load), consider optimization more. When it will be performed administratively or reflect persisting changes over time, consider accuracy and stability more heavily than optimization.

Comment: Thanks for you answers. It's only the administrators of the site which fires this trigger. Because it's only when the "activate plugin" action takes place it fires. And the only thing the trigger do is to lay in the database and wait for comments to be inserted and then update a column in the user table. the trigger works perfect when I create it in sql inside MySQL so I think it would be sad to destroy it and find a totally new approach. But i might need to do this if I can't find a solution.